# How can I tally up the total count of my columns?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid

I'm auto-generating my columns using a datagrid. How can I get a total of the created and redeemed columns?

```
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_TotalCount_p");
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@pDateFrom", DbType.Date, datePicker1.Text);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@pDateTo", DbType.Date, datepicker2.Text);
ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);

ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add("Total");

DataGrid2.DataSource = ds;
DataGrid2.DataBind();
```

[image: example datagrid]

Comment: What are `created` and `redeemed` columns? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Those are the columns coming back from SQL.

Comment: If you're getting the values from a stored procedure, why not have it return the totals as well?

Comment: im on sql server 2000 and it's too complicated to pivot the table the way I need. i thought it would be easier to count tally up the values of the columns afterwards using C#.

Answer (score 3):

Can write a "RowDataBound()" event and sum that up seperately. Something like below.

```
    public int totalCount = default(int);

    protected void Test_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType.Equals(DataControlRowType.DataRow))
        {
            int count = default(int);
            string text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            int.TryParse(text, out count);
            totalCount = totalCount + count;
        }
    }
```

Hope this is useful!!

Comment: Do I have to call that somewhere? How do I implement it into my code? I added it as a new method below my totalcount code.

Comment: You need to add an event "RowDataBound" if it's a GridView or "OnDataBound" (the <asp:DataGrid> tag contains this event) if it's a datagrid to the ".aspx page" and add this code to the corresponding ".cs" file which would give you the counts.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the sum of the columns, not the count, and assuming the schema of the returned DataSet is what you have shown, then try:

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
int totalCreated = 0;
int totalRedeemed = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    totalCreated += Convert.ToInt32(dr["Created"]);
    totalRedeemed += Convert.ToInt32(dr["Redeemed"]);
}

DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
r["CreationDate"] = "Total";
r["Created"] = totalCreated;
r["Redeemed"] = totalRedeemed;
dt.Rows.Add(r);
```

Be aware this adds the row to the DataSource and, so far as your DataGrid is concerned, it's just another row of data. Do not try to sort or edit the DataGrid.